# Can Android 6 backups be manually deleted?

Tags: backup, 6.0-marshmallow

When using the [new backup service](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) introduced with Android 6, is there any way to explicitly delete an existing backup of an Android device stored in a Google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Operating System blog (unofficial)](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-auto-backup.html) says

> The Android section from Google Dashboard shows a lot of useful information about your Android devices (IMEI number, registered date, last activity date, carrier) and it also lets you **delete backup data**. "Please note that new backup data will be created if backup is enabled on any of your Android devices," informs Google.

[XDA post-  How do I delete Google's Cloud Backups?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60520215&postcount=10) says the same, with a picture below

[image]

Disabling backup from *Settings* will prevent future backups but not delete earlier ones

**Disclaimer:** Unverified, since I don't make Google back ups