# Is there a way to reset my Android Google sync data?

Tags: sync, google-backup

I've been using Android since the days of Froyo (Android 2.2). My data would get synced normally using Android's Google sync feature.

I am not sure whether there has been of fundamental change in the way Google sync in Android since those days.  But I notice that my sync doesn't work properly.

Specifically:

- Contact sync:  restores only half of my contacts whenever I change phones. If I manually export/import contacts then it deletes half of my list on the next sync.  It just refuses to update the existing contact list present on the cloud.

  - Application data doesn't get transferred. I've seen other people changing their phones and I've seen that Google sync essentially restores their installed apps and then restores the data contained within them. In my case it restores apps that I used to have on my Froyo phone. And it doesn't restore any app data.

Is there a way I could reset all the data on my cloud sync so that Google sync can start doing a fresh start?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete synchronized Google data? (contacts, app data etc)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182322/how-can-i-delete-synchronized-google-data-contacts-app-data-etc)

Comment: Also see this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154293/131553